# Как настроить ssh для git на сервере?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, deploy

Не могу никак сделать git pull с помощью GitHub Actions.
Дано - репозиторий на GitHub, сервер и, собственно, сайт.

Зашел на сервер, создал ключи

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "mail@mail.com"
```

Сделал
`$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

и добавил ключ

```
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

После этого в папке .ssh сделал файл config и прописал

```
 Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Добавил на [github](https://docs.github.com/ru/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) публичный ключ

Сделал проверку на сервере

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Hi User! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Все вроде ок. При первой попытке action с workflow ругалось на то, что права у ключей слишком расширены — сделал chmod 400 на оба.

Получаю в action github

```
err: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

err: debug1: Reading configuration data /home/***/.ssh/config

err: debug1: /home/***/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com

err: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

err: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files

err: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

err: debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.

err: debug1: Connection established.

err: debug1: identity file /home/***/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3

err: debug1: identity file /home/***/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1

err: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1

err: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-1b199b0f

err: debug1: no match: babeld-1b199b0f

err: debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

err: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256

err: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

err: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none

err: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
err: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

err: debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMWu3/LiyfQM

err: debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.

err: debug1: Found key in /home/***/.ssh/known_hosts:1

err: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

err: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

err: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks

err: debug1: Will attempt key: /home/***/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:wBeVhufWuxwTRo explicit

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

err: debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>

err: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

err: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

err: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

err: debug1: Offering public key: /home/***/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:OAZaccdgduVhufWuxwTRo explicit

err: debug1: Server accepts key: /home/***/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:OAZ71DHXwBeVhufWuxwTRo explicit

err: debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
err: debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

**err: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
err: and the repository exists.**

Что еще ему нужно?

Comment: *"read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty"* Звучит как попытка запросить пароль от ключа, но т.к. нет интерактивного терминала, негде спрашивать. Сделайте ключ без пароля может?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут опущено самое важное - что собственно выполняется в github actions, и какую роль в них играют упомянутый сервер и сайт.